# Remove question mark in URL with "Force URL query strings" enabled

Tags: url, htaccess, segments, .htaccess, querystring

in one of my sites I had to enable "Force URL query strings" because my hosting provider doesn't have "URL Segment Support" enabled.

I don't have the permissions to change Apache configuration file directly.

To remove index.php I have this .htaccess

```
AcceptPathInfo On
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /

   # Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
   RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
   RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

   # Directs all EE web requests through the site index file
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Now the pages are something like

www.example.com/?/page

Is there a way to remove the question mark through .htaccess or should I ask to my hosting provider to enable URL Segment Support?

Thanks

Comment: Can any one find solution for this issue?

Comment: No, I finally asked my hosting provider to enable URL Segment Support.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue to this previously. Removing the "?" in the last RewriteRule solved the issue.

Change in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

To:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Hope this helps you as much as it did me.

Comment: I tried. In this way I can view the page  www.example.com/?/page  
but if I try to view the page  
www.example.com/page  
I view a blank page with the following error:  
No input file specified.  
In the other way I can view both versions of URLs but if I put  
{path='page'}  
in my template it returns me the one with the question mark.

Comment: OK, if you update `code`$config['uri_protocol'] = 'QUERY_STRING';`code` in your config.php file, as per [link]http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/urls/url_structure.html#query-strings[link] does this help?

Comment: Nothing changed